# Way to process an xml tree with attributes in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I still cannot find a good solution to process an xml tree like :

```xml
<root>
     <lv 1>
        <lv 2>
             <lv 3  d1="h1">
                <lv 4  dd1 = "detail 11">
                <lv 4  dd1 = "detail 12">
             </lv 3>
             <lv 3  d1="h2">
                <lv 4  dd1 = "detail 22">
             </lv 3>
        </lv 2>
     </lv 1>
   </root>
```

The problem is that I would like to directly go to "lv 3" and build back the relationship :

(h1, detail11)
(h1, detail12)
(h2, detail22)

I am not so experienced in C# and I have read through some examples and still cannot find out a good solution.

I would be much grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: This isn't valid XML and no XML tool or API will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

First, your xml is not an xml, valid representation is the following:

```
<root>
 <lv1>
    <lv2>
         <lv3  d1="h1">
            <lv4  dd1="detail 11"/>
            <lv4  dd1="detail 12"/>
         </lv3>
         <lv3  d1="h2">
            <lv4  dd1="detail 22"/>
         </lv3>
    </lv2>
 </lv1>
</root>
```

And having that you can write smth like this:

```
    var xml = @"<root>
        <lv1>
            <lv2>
                <lv3  d1=""h1"">
                    <lv4  dd1 = ""detail 11""/>
                    <lv4  dd1 = ""detail 12""/>
                </lv3>
                <lv3  d1=""h2"">
                    <lv4  dd1 = ""detail 22""/>
                </lv3>
            </lv2>
        </lv1>
    </root>";

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    foreach (XmlNode lv3Node in doc.SelectNodes("root/lv1/lv2/lv3"))
    {
        foreach (XmlNode lv4Node in lv3Node.SelectNodes("lv4"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lv3Node.Attributes["d1"].Value + ";" + lv4Node.Attributes["dd1"].Value);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
h1;detail 11
h1;detail 12
h2;detail 22
```

C# has 3 ways to work with XML:

- [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx) (based on XDocument) - nice syntax and pretty fast
- Using DOM (based on [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) - slow, but allows multiple traversals of the same xml
- [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - very fast, but cumersome and does not allow going backwards

Comment: A possible solution but maybe `<lv x="1">` is more appropriate than `<lv1>`.  The OP should repair the question.